# Create a graph of a column with gaps between data

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I'm trying to create graphs of every column of data in a worksheet. As of right now it works as long as there are no gaps in the column of data, but I need it to be robust enough that it works if there are gaps in the data. The data is entered in batches with different columns having different lengths due to different measurement requirements. Each of the rows will also have an identifier in the first column indicating what batch of data that row comes from (see attached file). Since the identifier column will be the same length as the longest data column, I compare the last row of that to the bottom row of any given data column to make sure all the data is getting graphed. However right now the it gets stuck in the loop if there's a gap in the data.

```vb
    Sub GraphAllColumns()
        Dim col As Range 'The cell at the top of the data column
        Dim bottomRow As Range
        Dim bottomData As Range
    
        Set col = ActiveSheet.Range("B7")
        Set bottomRow = Range("A7").End(xlDown)
    
        col.Select
    
        If Not IsEmpty(Selection) Then 'If the worksheet is empty, nothing happens
            Do
                Set bottomData = Selection.End(xlDown)
                If bottomRow.Row <= bottomData.Row Then
                    'Iterate through every column, select all the data in that column
                    'then call the create graph subroutine
                    Call CreateGraph
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                Else
                    If IsEmpty(Selection.End(xlDown)) Then
                        Call CreateGraph
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                    Else
                        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                    End If
                End If
            Loop Until IsEmpty(Selection)
        End If    
    End Sub

Here's the CreateGraph subroutine as well. I'm happy the way that it works. I know it isn't the best way, but this is my first time using VBA.

    Sub CreateGraph()
        Dim startCell As Range      'Starting cell (important for column selection)
        Dim graphRange As Range
    
        Set startCell = Selection
        Set graphRange = Range(startCell, startCell.End(xlDown))  'Selects all data in column
    
        'Create chart, define chart type and source data
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=graphRange
    
        'Change chart location so that all charts on a sheet are stacked in top left corner
        With ActiveChart.Parent
            .Top = Range("A1")
            .Left = Range("A1")
        End With
    
        'Change chart title and other attributes
        With ActiveChart
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = startCell.Offset(-2, 0).Value
        
        End With
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `Set bottomRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)` is a better approach

Comment: `IsEmpty(Selection)` doesn't do what you think it does - it will return `False` even when there's no data.

Comment: A screenshot of how your data is laid out would be useful here.  "See attached file" - there's no file?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited in a picture. I completely forgot about it.

Comment: So what would be the range for the first plot?  Still not sure I follow the steps accurately.

Comment: The first plot would be B7:B26, and that one is made perfectly by what I have. The second would be C7:C19 and C23:C26 and that's where it becomes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I may still be misunderstanding what you want, but this should get you started.

```vb
Sub PlotDataById()
    
    Dim dict As Object, id, ws As Worksheet, rngId As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
    
    Set dict = IdRanges(ws.Range("B3")) 'get the ranges for each id
    
    For Each id In dict
        Set rngId = dict(id).Offset(0, 1) 'first set of data
        Debug.Print "Plotting id - " & id & ":" & rngId.Address
        Do While Application.CountA(rngId) > 0
            'use resize() to pass only the occupied range
            CreateGraph rngId.Resize(Application.CountA(rngId)), id
            Set rngId = rngId.Offset(0, 1) 'next column over
        Loop
    Next id
    
End Sub

'Capture the ranges occupied by each id in a list, starting at `startCell`
'  Assumes list is sorted by id
Function IdRanges(startCell As Range) As Object
    Dim c As Range, id, currId, cStart As Range, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    currId = Chr(0) 'some non-value
    Set c = startCell
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
        id = c.Value
        If id <> currId Then
            If Not cStart Is Nothing Then
                dict.Add currId, c.Parent.Range(cStart, c.Offset(-1, 0))
            End If
            Set cStart = c
            currId = id
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    dict.Add currId, c.Parent.Range(cStart, c.Offset(-1, 0))
    Set IdRanges = dict
End Function

'Create a plot of `rngData` with title `chtTitle`
Sub CreateGraph(rngData As Range, chtTitle)
    Dim co As Shape, cht As Chart, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = rngData.Parent
    Set co = ws.Shapes.AddChart
    With co.Chart
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .SetSourceData Source:=rngData
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = chtTitle
    End With
    With co 'all charts on a sheet are stacked in top left corner
        .Top = ws.Range("A1").Top
        .Left = ws.Range("A1").Left
    End With
End Sub
```

Using Select/ActiveCell is not a very robust way to structure your code, and typically you can avoid almost all uses of that approach.